# Does only the group $SO(n)$ admit a double cover which is $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$?

Tags: lie-groups, spin-geometry

The double cover of the group $SO(n)$ is the spin group $\operatorname{Spin}(n)$.

Do any of the other groups $SU(n)$, $\operatorname{Sp}(n)$, $G_2$, $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$ have double covers?

If so what are they?

How do we prove it one way or the other?

Since each of these groups can be written as a subgroup of $SO(m)$ for some $m$, then this suggests to me there may be double covers that are the subgroup of $\operatorname{Spin}(m)$. Is this logic correct?

Answer (score 4):

$SU(n)$ is simply connected for $n \ge 2$ and $Sp(n)$ is simply connected for $n \ge 1$, so they don't have nontrivial *connected* covers (you can take their preimages in the spin group with respect to some embedding in an orthogonal group but they won't be connected).

For the others, a priori it depends on what group you mean. You've given names of Lie algebras and those Lie algebras correspond to many Lie groups. According to Wikipedia, the [compact real form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2_(mathematics)#Real_forms) of $G_2$ is simply connected and has trivial center, so it's the unique connected Lie group with Lie algebra the compact real form of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ and it has no nontrivial connected covers. Wiki also claims the same for [$F_4$ and $E_8$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_simple_Lie_groups#Compact) but says that there's a compact real form of $E_7$ with fundamental group $C_2$ and a compact real form of $E_6$ with fundamental group $C_3$. So there's a compact real form of $E_7$ with a nontrivial double cover. I don't know how to verify any of this.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if one can form a pair of groups A and B such that one is the double cover of the other (so can represent fermions in a sense) and that both have the same lie algebra. I am very interested if this has been shown for exceptional groups.

Comment: @zooby: see my edit. Apparently $E_7$ is the only possibility.

Comment: That surprises me. I would have guessed it would be $F_4$ as the best candidate.

Comment: Does that mean if you try to take the subgroup of the $Spin(n)$ group which gives the group we want, then the resulting group will not be connected? i.e. the surface representing it will split into two parts?

Comment: I would love to know if $E_7$ has a non-trivial double cover.

Comment: @zooby: yes, it won't be connected. And again, Wikipedia claims this for $E_7$ but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: Neither do I :)